# Test a stochastic gradient descent model in Apache Mahout in Java

Tags: java, classification, mahout

I am new with Apache Mahout and I was wondering how I could test a model that I trained with a stochastic gradient descent algorithm.

I got a Java example where I am training an OnlineLogisticRegression algorithm with the 20 news group dataset.

You can see this example here:

https://github.com/jpatanooga/MahoutExamples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudera/mahout/classification/sgd/TwentyNewsgroups.java

Now I have no java code to test my trained algorithm. As you know, after training algorithm , we need to test it.

In command line the mahout documentation suggests to do (this example is for nayve bayes classifier but I assume in SGD it should be the same )  :

```
  $ mahout testnb 
        -i ${WORK_DIR}/20news-test-vectors
        -m ${WORK_DIR}/model 
        -l ${WORK_DIR}/labelindex 
        -ow 
        -o ${WORK_DIR}/20news-testing 
        -c
```

I have my testing data set and my trained model. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In the [20 newsgroups tutorial](http://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/twenty-newsgroups.html), the [testing script for running the examples](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/examples/bin/classify-20newsgroups.sh) is discussed. Looking inside this script you can see that the *testnb* command is not used to test stochastic descent.

If you follow the instructions there (quoted below) you can run the stochastic descent model as they provide it -

> 

```
If running Hadoop in cluster mode, start the hadoop daemons by executing the following commands:

    $ cd $HADOOP_HOME/bin
    $ ./start-all.sh

Otherwise:

    $ export MAHOUT_LOCAL=true

In the trunk directory of Mahout, compile and install Mahout:

    $ cd $MAHOUT_HOME
    $ mvn -DskipTests clean install

Run the 20 newsgroups example script by executing:

    $ ./examples/bin/classify-20newsgroups.sh
```

If you'd like to know what they're doing, the key is in the last few lines of the script I mentioned above. The command that replaces *testnb* is as follows:

> ./bin/mahout org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TestNewsGroups --input ${WORK_DIR}/20news-bydate/20news-bydate-test/ --model /tmp/news-group.model